# Adding custom style in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created custom style as below

```
public class MenuStyle: StyleSelector
{
    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        // my code
    }
}
```

I am using this style in `xaml` file as below.

I am using it as below.

Added namespace as below

```
xmlns:style="clr-namespace:MedicalStore.Styles"
```

Added resource as

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <style:MenuStyle x:Key="MenuStyle"></style:MenuStyle> 
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="SelectedMenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

and using it as below

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="22" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="MainMenu"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Text" 
              ItemContainerStyleSelector="{Binding MenuStyle}">
        </Menu>
```

but as I run my app, debugger never goes to `MenuStyle` class. What is the issue?

Comment: You should use your resource via `{StaticResource MenuStyle}`, not as a binding source.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to write the style in code instead of xaml?

Comment: @Sham I would love to do it in XAML, but I couldn't find how to apply Style for alternate items only

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to implement `Style`-properties in your `MenuStyle`-Class.

```
public class MenuStyle : StyleSelector
{
    // Declare all the style you're going to need right here
    public Style StyleMenuItem { get; set; }

    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        // here you can check which type item is and return the corresponding style
        if(item != null && typeof(item) == typeof(YourType))
        {
             return StyleMenuItem;
        }
    }
}
```

With that, you can do following in your `XAML`

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem" x:Key="SelectedMenuItemStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <style:MenuStyle x:Key="MenuStyle" StyleMenuItem="{StaticResource SelectedMenuItemStyle}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Note that I changed the `x:Key` of your Style to make things more clear.

Next thing is in your `Menu`:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontSize="22" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="MainMenu"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Text" 
              ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource MenuStyle}">
</Menu>
```

There, you have to use `StaticResource` instead of `Binding`.
This should be all.